# Blueprint framework

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I'm currently restyling my web application, my friend suggested me to use a framework as blueprint, can someone please tell me if it's a good choice or if it has some cons ?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this article could be useful for you: [CSS Frameworks: Pros and Cons](http://designshack.co.uk/articles/css/css-frameworks-pros-and-cons).